# Perpare .txt file for PostgreSQL import with Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have test\result_wo_semicolon.txt file:

```
date;time;CO2;CH4
2012-03-29;20:13:20.464;6.2990027157E+002;1.1734711917E-001
2012-03-29;20:54:49.510

2012-03-29;20:55:40.511;-2.6541031080E-001;4.1844418258E-003
```

I want to import this .txt file to PostgreSQL database with Postgresql COPY command (delimiter ';'). COPY command gives me an error because of empty fields and empty rows. To make the import work I have to add 2 semicolons to the third row and 3 semicolons to 4th row (empty row). How can I achieve this with Python 3.5. (I'm using Windows 7). Code I have written so far:

```
with open('test\\result_wo_semicolon.txt','r')as o:
for line in o:
    semicolon_count=line.count(';')
    if semicolon_count<3:
        added_semicolons=';'*(int(3)-int(semicolon_count))#there is something wrong here
        with open ('test\\result_added_semicolons.txt','a')as t:
            t.write(line+added_semicolons)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a bug in your code because of the newlines. Just modify your code like this:

```
with open('test\\result_wo_semicolon.txt','r')as o:
    for raw_line in o:
    line = raw_line.strip()
    semicolon_count = line.count(';')
    if semicolon_count < 3:
        added_semicolons=  ';' * (3 - semicolon_count) # there is something wrong here
        with open ('test\\result_added_semicolons.txt','a')as t:
        t.write(line + added_semicolons + '\n')
```